# my binary search works but returns the wrong index

Tags: algorithm, haskell, binary-search-tree

I implemented a binary search function in haskell and I want to return the actual index of the number if I found it.

I tested the function many times and it always finds the number if it exists, but it writes out the wrong index in the end. I am trying to change it in every way, but I lost the logic. What am I doing wrong?

```hs
search :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Int
search _ _ [] = (-1)
search e i xs 
    | e == mid = (index + i)
    | e < mid = search e (i - index) prev
    | e > mid = search e (index + i + 1) next
    where
        index = length xs `quot` 2
        (mid: next) = drop index xs
        prev = take index xs
```

I am supposed to return the index of the element if i find it.

The `i` will be 0 on the first call, then it will grow and shrink in the recusion.

The input list `xs` is sorted in ascending order.

`e` is the element
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the point of the `i` argument?

Comment: General notice: it makes no sense whatsoever to search a _list_ this way, it'll actually be much slower than a simple exhaustive search.

Comment: @leftaroundabout `i` is the index, I have it as an argument because the function is recursive and the new index will be based on sublists, and I am required to return the index of the full list. I edited my question to add that

Comment: I am new to binary search in Haskell. I have a python mindset, so that might be the reason I do it this weird way.

Comment: What is the smallest input that behaves differently from your expectation?

Comment: To expand @leftroundabout's comment: your python code is doing a binary chop search, assuming the elements are in order. Are you sure the list is sorted? An exhaustive search will not only be simpler to code and quicker, it'll also work if the list is unsorted.

Comment: The `(i - index)` looks very curious to me. Why shouldn't that just be `i`?

Comment: Consider the case of searching for 0 in [0,1], `search 0 0 [0,1]`. Then your first recursion will be `search 0 (-1) [0]`.

Comment: @AntC It doesn't matter if the list is sorted or not. In Haskell all lists are linked lists, which means to index a list you have to look at all the values before it, so you might as well just loop through the list anyway.

Comment: Ok I see. I found out how to get the right index. I should just change the seccond pattern to have `e < mid = search e (i) prev` But it is still really slow, even my python code is faster. thank you @amalloy

Comment: it is slow because the efficiency of binary search is predicated on the access to nth element in the input being O(1), but with lists it is O(n). you end up re-traversing the list many many times instead of avoiding the traversals as binary search on direct-access data structure would do. better just do one traversal until you find it or overshoot it, and be done with it.

Comment: since you've solved the problem, it's OK to post your own answer and accept it to signal that the issue is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I found out how to get the right index. I should just change the second pattern to have

```
e < mid = search e (i) prev
```